# Sum values in a DataTable by a given criteria

Tags: c#, datatable

Which is the most effective way to sum data in the DataTable by a given criteria?

I have the following table:

```
KEY_1
KEY_2,
VALUE_1,
VALUE_2
```

Input:

```
01101, P, 2, 3
01101, F, 1, 1
01101, P, 4, 4
10102, F, 5, 7
```

Desired output (new DataTable):

```
01101, P, 6, 7
01101, F, 1, 1
01101, SUM, 7, 8
10102, F, 5, 7
10102, SUM, 5, 7
```

I need efficient algorithm, because I have 10k rows and 18 columns in a DataTable.

Thank you.

Comment: You really need to describe more precisely what you're trying to do... Your example is not very clear to us mere mortals ;)

Comment: I need to prepare data for custom reporting engine. It's weird, I know. But that's the task. I can't fire sql query and get desired values because it's very expensive operation for so much data.

Comment: @Paulo Santos, I don't have sample code. I have to write it. All I have is DataTable dt = _repository.GetData();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You may want to consider using LINQ** - it has a GroupBy operator which may allows you to do this easily with relatively good performance given teh data size you describe.

**If you need a super-optimized implementation**, then you may want to create your own intermediate data structure to represent a summed record, store that some kind of dictionary based on the key, and update it as you loop over each record.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! My application runs on .net 2.0 :( Will dictionary be a big overhead? It will contain at least 5k elements.

Comment: Dictionaries scale fairly well, so long as the key that you're using has a good distribution of hashvalues. It will also be a much faster implementation than other algorithsm (such as nested loops).